# Unable to stop a thread

Tags: java

Here is the code I'm using.

```
public class timerApp {
Runnable timerRun = new runX();
Thread thread1 = new Thread(timerRun);
public static void main(String[] args) {
    timerApp xyz = new timerApp();
    xyz.createGUI();
}
public void createGUI() {
    JButton button = new JButton("Start timer");
    JButton button2 = new JButton("Stop timer");
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    JLabel label = new JLabel("under_construction");
    frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.NORTH,button);
    frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.SOUTH,button2);
    frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.CENTER,label);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(500,500);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    button.addActionListener(new b1L());
    button2.addActionListener(new b2L());
}
public class b1L implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        thread1.start();
    }
}
public class b2L implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        thread1.stop();
    }
  }
}
```

I get an error `Note: timerApp.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.  Note: Recompile with Xlint:deprecation for details.`
I started getting this after adding the stop button's listener class.

RELP!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You get this warning as Thread's [stop()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#stop()) method is deprecated.

**Why is Thread.stop deprecated?**

> Because it is inherently unsafe.
>   Stopping a thread causes it to unlock
>   all the monitors that it has locked.
>   (The monitors are unlocked as the
>   ThreadDeath exception propagates up
>   the stack.) If any of the objects
>   previously protected by these monitors
>   were in an inconsistent state, other
>   threads may now view these objects in
>   an inconsistent state. Such objects
>   are said to be damaged. When threads
>   operate on damaged objects, arbitrary
>   behavior can result. This behavior may
>   be subtle and difficult to detect, or
>   it may be pronounced. Unlike other
>   unchecked exceptions, ThreadDeath
>   kills threads silently; thus, the user
>   has no warning that his program may be
>   corrupted. The corruption can manifest
>   itself at any time after the actual
>   damage occurs, even hours or days in
>   the future.

Nice link:

http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/misc/threadPrimitiveDeprecation.html

**This link provides info related to your question for :**

- Why is Thread.stop deprecated?
- What should I use instead of
  Thread.stop?
- How do I stop a thread that waits for
  long periods (e.g., for input)?
- What if a thread doesn't respond to
  Thread.interrupt?

[Why Are Thread.stop, Thread.suspend, Thread.resume and Runtime.runFinalizersOnExit Deprecated?](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/misc/threadPrimitiveDeprecation.html)

Answer (score 6):

`stop()` is indeed deprecated. It will leave the program in an inconsistent state. Better approaches are:

1. `Thread.interrupt()`
2. Setting a boolean visible in the thread, and getting that thread to check that variable regularly

See [here](http://forward.com.au/javaProgramming/HowToStopAThread.html) for more details on how to stop threads safely.

Answer (score 5):

First of all, that's not an error. It's a warning that you're using a deprecated method.

`Thread.stop()` is deprecated. You can read the rationale behind this [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/misc/threadPrimitiveDeprecation.html).

Basically their argument is that there is no safe way of terminating a thread from the outside; therefore the only way you should use would be to politely ask the thread to stop:

> **What should I use instead of
>   Thread.stop?**
>
> Most uses of stop should
>   be replaced by code that simply
>   modifies some variable to indicate
>   that the target thread should stop
>   running. The target thread should
>   check this variable regularly, and
>   return from its run method in an
>   orderly fashion if the variable
>   indicates that it is to stop running.
>   (This is the approach that JavaSoft's
>   Tutorial has always recommended.) To
>   ensure prompt communication of the
>   stop-request, the variable must be
>   volatile (or access to the variable
>   must be synchronized).
>
> For example, suppose your applet
>   contains the following start, stop and
>   run methods:
>
> ```
> private Thread blinker;
>
> public void start() {
>     blinker = new Thread(this);
>     blinker.start();
> }
>
> public void stop() {
>     blinker.stop();  // UNSAFE!
> }
>
> public void run() {
>     Thread thisThread = Thread.currentThread();
>     while (true) {
>         try {
>             thisThread.sleep(interval);
>         } catch (InterruptedException e){
>         }
>         repaint();
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> You can avoid the use of Thread.stop
>   by replacing the applet's stop and run
>   methods with:
>
> ```
> private volatile Thread blinker;
>
> public void stop() {
>     blinker = null;
> }
>
> public void run() {
>     Thread thisThread = Thread.currentThread();
>     while (blinker == thisThread) {
>         try {
>             thisThread.sleep(interval);
>         } catch (InterruptedException e){
>         }
>         repaint();
>     }
> }
> ```